# input autocomplete is not working for any input

Tags: javascript, html, web, input, autocomplete

So far I've been having an interesting issue with Chrome specifically.  I'm trying to get rid of autocomplete completely.  Dealing specifically with address fields, if I set `<input autocomplete="off" ...>`, historical addresses are not shown but saved address (what you see in Settings > Autofill > Addresses and more) are shown. If I switch the value of autocomplete to a non-standard value `<input autocomplete="field" ..>`, Chrome doesn't show saved addresses but goes back to showing historical addresses. Is there a way to hide both autocomplete functionalities?

Edit: This is the exact problem I am facing in this Google groups [post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/FmI4deui9Pk?pli=1).